# Pass value between express routes

Tags: express

I have an html form in one of my views. One value in that form is a username. I gave that input an id.

```
<input name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
```

When the form is submitted, I redirect to a new view.

```
res.redirect('/nextView');
```

nextView has a javascript file being served to it from my public folder. In that javascript file, I am trying to access the username value like this:

```
$('#username').val()
```

This is not working. I think it's because now that I am on nextView, the id 'username' does not exist.

How can I persist this value from one view to the next?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a URL with a query parameter attached or save a cookie value.

To attach a query parameter:

```
res.redirect('/nextView?userName=' + username)
```

To read from a query parameter in the browser use a queryParam parser. [Example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-query-params-object/)